# Firebase rtdb increment server value by server value?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have tried 2 ways but it does not work. Basically I want to increment a value on the realtime database by another value on same database. I do not want to read the value then add it as it is slower that way.

```
firebase.database().ref("life/").update({
  daya : firebase.database.ServerValue.increment(h.val())
}).catch((error) => {
  alert(error)
});
```

```
firebase.database().ref("life/").update({
  daya : daya + h
}).catch((error) => {
  alert(error)
});
```

Comment: What is `h` in the code you shared? Can you show how it's initialized?

Comment: h is a value on the database in the same directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*This is what I think you're trying to do, but I may update based on your response to my comment.*

The value by which to increment the property in the database must be a constant. There is no way to increment by the value of another property with the `increment` operation. You will have to first read that value into your application code, and then pass it to `increment`.

Comment: So there is no way to pass another database value in and increment.

Comment: You will have to first read that value into your application code, and then pass it to `increment`.